# Replace a certain value in OCaml list in every occurrence with another value

Tags: list, recursion, pattern-matching, ocaml

I'm working out a simple program that replaces a certain value (in every occurrence) with another given value inside a list. I tried to follow this:
[Ocaml, replace all specified elements with a given element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272115/ocaml-replace-all-specified-elements-with-a-given-element-in-a-list)

But unfortunately I can't use the `when` construct here. Here's my code:

```
let rec replace (l:int list) (i:int) (j:int) :int list =
    match l with
        | hd::tl -> if hd = i then j::tl else replace tl i j
        | [] -> l
;;
```

When I tried to replace an entry, It doesn't gives the whole list. instead it only gives the changed value. Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description of the problem doesn't match your code, or maybe I don't understand. If I try your code here's what I see:

```
# replace [1; 4; 1; 4; 2] 4 6 ;;
- : int list = [6; 1; 4; 2]
```

I see two problems. First, the return value starts at the first replaced value rather than the beginning of the list. Second, only one value is replaced, not all values.

To solve the first problem, you have to make sure you return the full list all the time. You're not returning the full list when `hd = i` is false.

To solve the second problem you need to process the tail of the list in all cases. You're not processing the tail of the list when `hd = i` is true.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity of my question as my english knowladge isn't that good. The thing I Need to do is
        # replace [1; 4; 1; 4; 2] 4 6;;
        - : int list = [1; 6; 1; 6; 2]
asyou can see all i need is to replace all the 4'sby 6's

Comment: Can you please explain how to maintain the tail when hd = i is true ?

Comment: Call `replace` recursively on the tail!